# Continuity of function proof

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $f:X \to Y \times Z$ be given by $f(x)=\bigl( f_{1}(x), f_{2}(x) \bigr)$. Prove that $f$ is continuous iff $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are continuous.

I'm struggling to relate the pre image of $h$ with the pre images of $h_{1}$ and $h_{2}$.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to specify the topology on $Y \times Z$

Comment: @DavidHolden box topology

Comment: so for a given $x \in X$ take a box around $f(x)$, and find a neighbourhood $N_x$ of $x$ which ensures that for any $x' \in N_x$  $f(x')$ is guaranteed to be in the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to check that inverse images of $f$ of basic open sets $U \times V$ of $Y \times Z$ (so $U \subset Y$ open and $V \subset Z$ open) are open.

Then note that $f^{-1}[U \times V] = f_1^{-1}[U] \cap f_2^{-1}[V]$ and proceed from that.

For the other direction, $\pi_Y \circ f = f_1$, where $\pi_Y$ is the projection onto $Y$. Likewise for the other projection and $f_2$.